# Categorize XML based on element attribute type

Tags: xslt

With this XML input I am unable to add elements to specific sections.

```
<Country>
  <info enum="CTRY" name="United Sates of America" total-states="50" />
  <info enum="ST" name="New York" population="8,244,910"/>
  <info enum="ST" name="Chicago" population="2,707,120"/>
  <info enum="CTRY" name="Germany" total-states="16"/>
  <info enum="ST" name="Berlin" population="3,469,910"/>
  <info enum="ST" name="Brandenburg" population="2,500,000"/>
</Country>
```

Here is my XSL,

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Country>
    <xsl:for-each select="Country/info">
      <xsl:if test="@enum='CTRY'">
        <CountryInfo>
          <name>Country Name: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></name>
          <districts><xsl:value-of select="@total-states"></xsl:value-of></districts>
          <xsl:for-each select="/Country/info">
            <xsl:if test="@enum='ST'">
              <state>
                <stateName>State Name: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></stateName>
                <statePop>State Population: <xsl:value-of select="@population"/></statePop>
              </state>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </CountryInfo>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Country>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that all the states are showing up for both countries.

Here is the XML output that I am trying to generate,

```
<Country>
  <CountryInfo>
    <name>Country Name: United Sates of America</name>
    <districts>50</districts>
    <state>
      <stateName>State Name: New York</stateName>
      <statePop>State Population: 8,244,910</statePop>
    </state>
    <state>
      <stateName>State Name: Chicago</stateName>
      <statePop>State Population: 2,707,120</statePop>
    </state>
  </CountryInfo>
  <CountryInfo>
    <name>Country Name: Germany</name>
    <districts>16</districts>
    <state>
      <stateName>State Name: Berlin</stateName>
      <statePop>State Population: 3,469,910</statePop>
    </state>
    <state>
      <stateName>State Name: Brandenburg</stateName>
      <statePop>State Population: 2,500,000</statePop>
    </state>
  </CountryInfo>
</Country>
```

Is it possible to accomplish this with XSLT?

Comment: It would help if you showed your stylesheet. All you have in your post is a single template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source is a dreadful abuse of XML! You should complain bitterly to whoever designed and provided you with such rubbish.

With a single template you can't do anything more than remove or expand on elements that are already in the source.

I believe this transform does what you need. It works by copying the `Country` root element and processing its contents. The second template matches all of the `info` elements that have an `enum` attribute of `CTRY`, which form the basis for the `CountryInfo` output elements.

The state information has to be done recursively, by using `call-template` to insert the information from the following `info` element if it has an `enum` attribute of `ST`.

Because of the structure of the source data this transform is very fragile, and will break if there are any unexpected elements. Please beware.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Country">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="info[@enum='CTRY']">
    <CountryInfo>
      <name>
        <xsl:text>Country name: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </name>
      <districts>
        <xsl:value-of select="@total-states"/>
      </districts>
      <xsl:call-template name="state"/>
    </CountryInfo>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="state">
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::info[$i][@enum='ST']">
      <state>
        <stateName>
          <xsl:text>State Name: </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::info[$i]/@name"/>
        </stateName>
        <statePop>
          <xsl:text>State Population: </xsl:text> 
          <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::info[$i]/@population"/>
        </statePop>
      </state>
      <xsl:call-template name="state">
        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i+1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Country>
   <CountryInfo>
      <name>Country name: United States of America</name>
      <districts>50</districts>
      <state>
         <stateName>State Name: New York</stateName>
         <statePop>State Population: 8,244,910</statePop>
      </state>
      <state>
         <stateName>State Name: Chicago</stateName>
         <statePop>State Population: 2,707,120</statePop>
      </state>
   </CountryInfo>
   <CountryInfo>
      <name>Country name: Germany</name>
      <districts>16</districts>
      <state>
         <stateName>State Name: Berlin</stateName>
         <statePop>State Population: 3,469,910</statePop>
      </state>
      <state>
         <stateName>State Name: Brandenburg</stateName>
         <statePop>State Population: 2,500,000</statePop>
      </state>
   </CountryInfo>
</Country>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were producing a full list of all states because inside of your `<xsl:for-each>` you had another `<xsl:for-each>` that was selecting *ALL* of the states by "jumping up" to the root node with `/Country/info`.

In this instance, for each "country" element you want to find all of the `info` elements with `@enum='ST' who's nearest preceding`info`element with`@enum='CTRY'` is the current one to produce the "states".

Rather than approaching it from a "pull" style, look to "push" the right content and match the patterns that apply. It will make your XSLT easier to produce and help modularize into distinct templates that are easier to maintain (and easier to override if/when you get to importing).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Country">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="info[@enum='CTRY']"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="info[@enum='CTRY']">
        <CountryInfo>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></name>
            <districts><xsl:value-of select="@total-states"/></districts>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                       select="following-sibling::info[@enum='ST']
                                  [generate-id(
                                      preceding-sibling::info[@enum='CTRY'][1])
                                   = generate-id(current())]"/>
        </CountryInfo>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="info[@enum='ST']">
        <state>
            <stateName>
                <xsl:text>State Name: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </stateName>
            <statePop>
                <xsl:text>State Population: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@population"/>
            </statePop>
        </state>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This short and simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kStates" match="info[@enum='ST']"
          use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::info[@enum='CTRY'][1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Country>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="info[@enum='CTRY']"/>
  </Country>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="info[@enum='CTRY']">
  <CountryInfo>
    <name>Country Name: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></name>
    <districts><xsl:value-of select="@total-states"/></districts>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kStates', generate-id())"/>
  </CountryInfo>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="info[@enum='ST']">
  <state>
    <stateName>State Name:<xsl:value-of select="@name"/></stateName>
    <statePop>State Population: <xsl:value-of select="@population"/></statePop>
  </state>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document (not dreadful at all :)  ):**

```
<Country>
  <info enum="CTRY" name="United Sates of America" total-states="50" />
  <info enum="ST" name="New York" population="8,244,910"/>
  <info enum="ST" name="Chicago" population="2,707,120"/>
  <info enum="CTRY" name="Germany" total-states="16"/>
  <info enum="ST" name="Berlin" population="3,469,910"/>
  <info enum="ST" name="Brandenburg" population="2,500,000"/>
</Country>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Country>
   <CountryInfo>
      <name>Country Name: United Sates of America</name>
      <districts>50</districts>
      <state>
         <stateName>State Name:New York</stateName>
         <statePop>State Population: 8,244,910</statePop>
      </state>
      <state>
         <stateName>State Name:Chicago</stateName>
         <statePop>State Population: 2,707,120</statePop>
      </state>
   </CountryInfo>
   <CountryInfo>
      <name>Country Name: Germany</name>
      <districts>16</districts>
      <state>
         <stateName>State Name:Berlin</stateName>
         <statePop>State Population: 3,469,910</statePop>
      </state>
      <state>
         <stateName>State Name:Brandenburg</stateName>
         <statePop>State Population: 2,500,000</statePop>
      </state>
   </CountryInfo>
</Country>
```